# How can we block mailto: links using Requestly

Tags: email, blocking, links, requestly

Can someone tell me if it's possible to block a mailto: function/link using [Requestly Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) ?

If possible, how can we do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to block `mailto:` links in your browser using Requestly. Here is a screenshot of Cancel/Block Rule to achieve this.

[image]

Here are the steps to get the rule :-

1. Install the Requestly Extension [for Chrome/Firefox](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/04/07/install-requestly-in-chrome-and-firefox/)
2. Open https://app.requestly.in/rules/#sharedList/1575428632331-Block-Mailto-links
3. Click Import List